# Как добавить пользователья на экран браузера из Input полей

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Нужно иметь Имя Фамилия и email указав данные они должны добавиться на экран браузера

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/form

Comment: Моя твоя не понимать. В чём возникла проблема?

Comment: Нужно иметь поле input Имя, Фамилия, возраст, email при клике на отправить нужно что бы данные передались на экран браузера

Answer (score 1):

Вот так

```html
<div class="data"></div>


Имя <input type="text" id='name'><br>
ФАмилия <input type="text" id='surname'><br>
Возраст <input type="text" id="age"><br>
email <input type="text" id="email"><br>
<button id="btn">Clickme!</button>


<script type="text/javascript">

var data = document.querySelector('.data');
var button = document.querySelector('#btn');
button.onclick = function () {
 /* body... */
var name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
var surname = document.querySelector('#surname').value;
var age = document.querySelector('#age').value;
var email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
 data.innerHTML = 'Имя ' + name + '<br>Фамилия '+ surname + '<br> Возраст ' +age + '<br> email ' + email+'<br><br>' ;
};



</script>
```